# web.config block access and use xml to access

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to block access to folder "admin", and only who will insert username & password by next xml (login.xml) info, will login:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<employee>
    <User>
        <username>master</username>
        <password>123</password>
    </User>
</employee>
```

I dont sure - i will use VWD2010 generated login page? if yes/no, how?

I know to do that by MSSQL, its generated by the VWD2010 as account folder, but i dont have idea how to set it by XML.

I am using c# for behind code.

Comment: could not understand your question. can you please share more details

Comment: asp.net web site, i want to block access for folder "admin" and grant access by username and password from xml file, not from sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Custom MembershipProvider and implement atleast ValidateUser method to check against your XML if user is valid.  you'll need to set your Custom MembershipProvider as a default one in web config of your project

Take a look at this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers